# Is there any way to disable swipe-gesture only on one page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swipe, onsen-ui

I know, that i can disable swipe at all by this code:

```
<ons-sliding-menu   var="AppMenu" 
                    menu-page="menu.html" 
                    main-page="login.html" 
                    side="left" 
                    swipeable="false">
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

But it will be nice to disable swipe only on login page. I guess, that there is a way to solve this problem using this code:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope){
    setSwipeable(False);
};
```

But it don't work correctly. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Use `AppMenu.setSwipeable(false)` instead and it should work. You'll need to reset it in the other controllers.

Comment: How about not adapting ons-sliding-menu to Login Page? After Logging in, ons.navigator.pushPage() to sliding-menu page should work well.

Comment: Thank you, Andreas! But the better way to solve it: use swipeable="false" by default and set AppMenu.setSwipeable(false) only on some pages. Your solution work too, but in first seconds of work, user may swipe very fast, so AppMenu.setSwipeable(false) wouldn't activate at time and menu would turn on